# SharePoint 2013 - Cloud Share App error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I am using "Cloud Share" SharePoint 2013 VM and just write a hello world , SharePoint 2013 - Auto Hosted App. While build the solution, I got the below error:

```
Error   1   Error occurred in deployment step 'Install App for SharePoint': Failed to install App for SharePoint.
```

How to resolve this error.

Comment: Did you make these settings ? http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2012/07/29/setting-up-your-app-domain-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps:
http://blog.mmasood.com/2013/02/configuring-app-domain-in-cloudshare.html

Not sure if this would apply for Auto Hosted Apps. But the deployment works for SharePoint Hosted apps once you do the steps in above-mentioned URL.

Regards,
Anwar

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link is broken, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I blogged about your exact issue here:
http://blog.cloudshare.com/2012/11/09/setting-up-the-cloudshare-sharepoint-2013-rtm-farm-to-support-apps/

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link is broken, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)